# How are decimal operations calculated?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I understand the regular CPU does arithmetic for whole number types (e.g. integers) as well as bitwise operations; the FPU does floating point arithmetic. However I'm trying to learn how/where does arithmetic for Decimal data types ([example for c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)) occur inside a typical processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation question... You can get the precise information by compiling the specific code to assembly [see this StackExchange article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021874/how-can-i-compile-to-assembly-with-gcc)

To the extent that it isn't an implementation question, you can see from here [remarks on the internal representation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx#Remarks) that there are three parts to the object:

- S = Sign bit
- I = 96-bit integer
- F = A "scale factor"

The value is calculated using a formula like:

```
value = ( S * I ) / ( 10 ^ F )
```

There are shortcuts that can be taken from these values that take advantage of things the CPU does easily.  The compiler / library probably implement these shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Integer arithmetic is processed by one of the basic functional blocks of the CPU known as the [Arithmetic Logic Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) or ALU.

The ALU can perform various integer addition, subtraction and mutiplications as well as logical operations on data.

Just because this unit works using integers does not mean that you cannot do floating point math, it will just be slower than a dedicated FPU.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108279/floating-point-math-on-a-processor-that-does-not-support-it) for some details.